# How to check which option is selected in mat-select angular 8 unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript2.0

```
it( 'Should set the initial value for test dropdown', async () => {
    let testDropdown : HTMLElement;
    const debugElement : DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    testDropdown = debugElement.queryAll( By.css( 'mat-select' ) )[ 0 ].nativeElement;
    expect( testDropdown ).toBeTruthy();
// How to get the selected value from the mat-select, like below code, which is not working
    console.log( testDropdown.children[ 0 ].innerHTML ); 
} );
```

In the HTML template, I am setting the default value for mat-select while looping options. How to get that selected value in unit testing

Answer (score 0):

May the material test source can help you with that: 
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select.spec.ts

```
      it('should be able to select an option using the MatOption API', fakeAsync(() => {
        trigger.click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        flush();

        const optionInstances = fixture.componentInstance.options.toArray();
        const optionNodes: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> =
            overlayContainerElement.querySelectorAll('mat-option');

        optionInstances[1].select();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(optionNodes[1].classList).toContain('mat-selected');
        expect(optionInstances[1].selected).toBe(true);
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.select.selected).toBe(optionInstances[1]);
      }));
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, with the shared link, I got an idea to get the selected value. I have used `getAttribute()` on `mat-select` element method to get the `ng-reflect-value` which holds the selected value string.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that in a `mat-select`, the nested `mat-option` elements are actually removed from the DOM so they can be inserted into an overlay, but if you're only interested in the currently selected option, you can grab the `<span>` that holds the current value with:

```
const selectValue = fixture.debugElement.query(
  By.css(".mat-select-value-text span")
).nativeElement.textContent;
```

It does sort of rely on an implementation detail -- the fact that the value is kept in a block element with the `mat-select-value-text` class when the `mat-select` is "closed" -- but I don't think that detail has changed for a long time, and it should fail loudly if it changes in the future.